# My in-app purchases is not working in production mode in android?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have developed one application in android with in-app purchases feature.

First I tested my application with test purchases using android.test.purchased it works fine when I tested using test purchases.

Second I uploaded new application with different SKU like product id's
 in playstore as a beta version and I tested that application using test accounts then also it is working fine and it is purchased. And I added in-app products in playstore.

But the problem is when I promote my beta test version into production it is not purchasing what I want, first it is purchasing and when I click one next time again also it is asking for purchase so every time it asking for purchase it s not proceeding to next action.

I followed [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Integrating_Google_Play_In-app_Billing_into_an_Android_Application_%E2%80%93_A_Tutorial) tutorial to implement in-app purchases    [in-app purcahses in android

Comment: some one giving negative votes please comment or edit post if don't understand anything,don't give any negative votes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my application I have used **mHelper.onConsumeAsync()**. So I removed this method when I click on the button so next time it is not consuming(means not asking for purchase second time).

So it is useful for consumable products like subscribed products(Non-Managed products).So I am not used that kind of products I used only Managed products when purchase product I am not purchasing again and these transaction will be managed by google.